# Sum of squares of sines.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Any ideas on how to compute this sum? I'm sure there's a simple trick to it, but I just can't wrap my mind around it at the moment. Some insight would be tremendously appreciated, thanks!

> $$\sum_{n = 1}^{90} \sin^2(n^\circ) \approx 45.5$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Compare $\sin(1^{\circ})^2$ and $\sin(89^{\circ})^2$.  What connection can you find?  Do the same with $\sin(2^{\circ})^2$ and $\sin(88^{\circ})^2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: 1) $\sin^2x = \dfrac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$

2) Find a closed form for the quite popular sum: $\cos 2x + \cos 4x + ....+ \cos 2nx$

Answer (score 3):

**Hints:** Can you use the following facts to sum your series in pairs?

- $\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta$
- $\cos(90^\mathrm o-\theta)=\sin \theta$

For example, $$\sin^2(5^\mathrm o)=1-\cos^2(5^\mathrm o)=1-\sin^2(85^\mathrm o)$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that
$$\sin(z) = {e^z - e^{-iz}\over 2i}.$$ and turn this into a messy geometric sum.

Comment: You can then resolve this in general.